# Piechart animation completed event

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

```
CGFloat radius = 100;
CAShapeLayer *pieShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pieShape.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(100, 300, radius, radius)
                                           cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;

pieShape.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
pieShape.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
pieShape.lineWidth   = 100;

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 15.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[pieShape addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
```

Above code is working fine.
But my problem is how can know that the duration 15 second is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the animation has completed using the superclass `CAAnimation` delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

If the duration is specified as 15.0 seconds and the `animationDidStop` has been invoked with `finished` set to `YES`, the you know that the time has elapsed.

Comment: Thx...you save my time alot.